# Update table from different table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, update

```
UPDATE RBI.RBI_OV_F_DETAIL A
     SET (BRANCH_ID, BRANCH_NUMBER) = (
           SELECT PRICE_BRANCH_ID, PRICE_BRANCH
             FROM RSE.RSE_SO_F_ORDERS B
                WHERE A.SOURCE_ID = B.FULL_ORDER_NUMBER AND A.METRIC_GROUP_ID='1');
```

I am getting error in this syntax:
single query returns multiple rows

Please suggest what to do.

Comment: First of all: This is not a syntax error as your statement is syntactically valid SQL.

Comment: You need to check the `where` clause in the subquery to make sure it is returning a single row for each row of the table you're trying to update. In my experience, looking at what the primary or unique keys are helps a lot.

Comment: can i add rownum=1 ? is that valid to add rownum=1

Comment: RDBMS??
If its Oracle, may you want to use MERGE statement
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm

Comment: i am using oracle 11g

Comment: Using MERGE won't help with this, @vegatripy

Comment: I wouldn't add `ROWNUM = 1` unless for a single row of the table you're trying to update all rows returned by the subquery have the same values. In that case adding `DISTINCT` to the subquery would have the same functional effect. So add `DISTINCT` first. If you still get the same error, than adding `ROWNUM = 1` is dangerous as you are selecting the first row of multiple where they are different...

Comment: You need to ensure that your sub-query returns exactly one row and not more when it does.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty answer:

```
UPDATE RBI.RBI_OV_F_DETAIL A
 SET (BRANCH_ID, BRANCH_NUMBER) = (
       SELECT PRICE_BRANCH_ID, PRICE_BRANCH
         FROM RSE.RSE_SO_F_ORDERS B
            WHERE A.SOURCE_ID = B.FULL_ORDER_NUMBER AND A.METRIC_GROUP_ID='1'
       group by price_branch_id, price_branch);
```

However if you're not expecting duplicates in the `RSE.RSE_SO_F_ORDERS` table, the more accurate answer would be to hunt down why those duplicates are there, and work with any stakeholders to eliminate the duplicates.